# Solve $\frac{4}{x+3}-\frac{2}{x+1}=\frac{5}{2x+6}-\frac{2\frac{1}{2}}{2x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $\dfrac{4}{x+3}-\dfrac{2}{x+1}=\dfrac{5}{2x+6}-\dfrac{2\frac{1}{2}}{2x+2}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{4}{x+3}-\dfrac{2}{x+1}=\dfrac{5}{2x+6}-\dfrac{5(2x+2)}{2} \ \ \ ...(1)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{4}{x+3}-\dfrac{2}{x+1}=\dfrac{5}{2(x+3)}-5(x+1) \ \ \ ...(2)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{4(x+1)-2(x+3)}{(x+1)(x+3)}=\dfrac{5-10(x+1)(x+3)}{2(x+3)} \ \ \ ...(3)$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{8(x+1)-4(x+3)}{(x+1)}=5-10(x+1)(x+3) \ \ \ ...(4)$

So far computationally all looks correct, however if I keep going obviously on the right hand side there will be a $x^3$ term and then it becomes quite complicated and tedious. I'm wondering if I missed a simplification somewhere or there's something else I can do to avoid a third power of $x$ showing up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you realize that you have twice the same denominator ?

Comment: (1) is wrong and has led to an $x^3$ term. The $(2x+2)$ can't hop from the bottom to the top of the fraction that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

Notice that there are $2x+6=2(x+3)\ne0$ and $2x+2=2(x+1)\ne 0$, then we have $x\ne-3$, $x\ne -1$, and

\begin{align}
&\frac{4}{x+3}-\frac{2}{x+1}=\frac{5}{2x+6}-\frac{\frac{5}{2}}{2x+2}\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~~&\frac{2\times4}{2(x+3)}-\frac{2\times2}{2(x+1)}=\frac{5}{2x+6}-\frac{\frac{5}{2}}{2x+2}\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~~&\color{red}{\frac{8}{2x+6}}-\color{blue}{\frac{4}{2x+2}}=\color{red}{\frac{5}{2x+6}}-\color{blue}{\frac{\frac{5}{2}}{2x+2}}\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~~&\color{red}{\frac{8}{2x+6}}-\color{red}{\frac{5}{2x+6}}=\color{blue}{\frac{4}{2x+2}}-\color{blue}{\frac{\frac{5}{2}}{2x+2}}\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~~&\color{red}{\frac{3}{2x+6}}=\color{blue}{\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{2x+2}}\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~~&3(2x+2)=\frac{3}{2}(2x+6)\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~~&6x+6=3x+9\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~~&3x=3\\
\Leftrightarrow~~~~&x=1.
\end{align}

The solution is done.

Comment: Downvoted. The person did not ask for a solution to the problem, they asked where they had gone wrong.

Comment: @Paul, the OP also mentioned that if there is anything else he can do to avoid an $x^3$ term showing up and this answer satisfies that.

Comment: Hi @Paul, thanks for your very kind reminder, and for accurately pointing out the wrong step (1) from the original poster and the incompleteness of this solution post.